# In C, error handling with an IF statement

Tags: c, error-handling

I need to fix some code that had

```
if ( abs(( (a/b) - (c/d) ) / (a/b)) > 0.1) { ...
```

This is part of a check to determine if these values make sense. If not, it will requery the values. There are checks beforehand to ensure it is not dividing by zero at any point but that equation would sometimes have floating point underflow errors. I'm trying to figure out a way to run this that will eliminate any possible errors.

Try and catch are out since this is in C not C++, setjmp and longjmp only seem to work if you can 'throw' the error yourself (I haven't seen any examples were the program causes the error that triggers it)

My solution that compiles but is hard to test (because it's part of a whole system):

```
if (val = abs(( (a/b) - (c/d) ) / (a/b)){
      if (val > 0.1) {
```

If the statement within the 'if' statement tries to throw an error, will it stop the program or will it just skip the if statement?

Any other ideas welcome

Comment: I don't think there's any way to detect floating point underflow/overflow in C.

Comment: how does an "if" statement throw an error? What error?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but it sure would be useful to wrap that condition up in a function with a meaningful name.

Comment: The C standard does cover the possible existence of floating point exceptions and underflow/overflow events, but it's implementation-defined. See section 7.6 of the standard as pertains to the ```fenv.h``` header.

Comment: Might be safer to add logic to each of the calculations and log any incoming values that would break the calculation before it does, if the system does not depend on that specific calculation to continue. E.g. check the range of (a/b) - (c/d) and then (a/b) and detect an overflow or underflow. What hardware is this that causes an underflow?

Comment: Why are you calculating `(a/b - c/d) / (a/b)` rather than the algebraically equivalent `1 - (b*c)/(a*d)`? Is there some numerical issue you are trying to deal with?

Comment: To me it unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to check if an operation will cause an underflow (i.e. before executing the operation) or are you asking what happens when an operation underflows?

Comment: OT: "... but is hard to test (**because it's part of a whole system**)" Something like this is to be tested in a small "stand-alone" program. Not as part of "the whole system".

Answer (score 1):

Common C implementations continue when there is a a floating-point division by zero, with the result set to +∞, −∞, or a NaN, depending on the operands. You should test `b` and `a/b` to see whether they are zero before performing the divisions by them, and you should also consider other conditions of interest, such as NaNs. E.g., if `a/b` and `c/d` overflow, your calculation will result in a NaN being compared to `.1`, which will evaluate as false, and so the code will fail to detect this, but you likely want to regard it as an error.

Also, `abs` is an `int` function. For floating-point absolute value, use `fabsf`, `fabs`, or `fabsl`, for `float`, `double`, or `long double`.

Answer (score 0):

> If the statement within the 'if' statement tries to throw an error, will it stop the program or will it just skip the if statement?

Supposing that the behavior of the expression in the outer `if` condition is defined in the first place, the only alternatives are that it evaluates to a floating-point value (possibly an infinity or NaN), or it performs a trap.

The latter is my best guess as to what you mean by "throw an error", and if the program performs a trap then, by definition, that interrupts its execution then and there (but not necessarily without the possibility of continuing).  That's completely unrelated to the context in which the trap is performed.

It is not the default behavior of most systems for floating-point underflow to cause a trap, but many systems provide the possibility of enabling traps for exceptional FP conditions such as that.  One option would be simply to turn that off, at least for the evaluation of that condition.  It could look like this:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

// ...

    fenv_t env;

    // Preserve the current FP environment and set a mode that prevents trapping
    // when FP exceptions are raised.
    feholdexcept(&env);

    if ( abs(( (a/b) - (c/d) ) / (a/b)) > 0.1) {
        // ... 
    }

    // Restore the FP environment
    fesetenv(&env);
```